# Emojis ruin postgresql ts_vector document search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

I came across a weird problem while working with `ts_vector()` function in `postgresql`.

**If the input document (text) contains emojis, output vector is illogical:**

Wrong matches when any emoji is present

```
SELECT to_tsvector('simple', 'This day is a good day.  Šodiena ir laba ir diena'); 

-- returns ' ':4 'aba ':9 'ay ':2 'ay.':6 'his ':1 'iena':11 'odiena ':7 'ood ':5 'r ':8,10 's ':3
```

Normal matches

```
SELECT to_tsvector('simple', 'This day is a good day. Šodiena ir laba ir diena') 

-- 'a':4 'day':2,6 'diena':11 'good':5 'ir':8,10 'is':3 'laba':9 'this':1 'šodiena':7
```

As you can see - the word matches are totally off when an emoji is present.
I am using UTF-8 characters. 
Both `CLIENT_ENCODING` and `SERVER_ENCODING` are `UTF8` 
`default_text_search_config` is `pg_catalog.english`

**Question: How to have meaningful results with emoji-contained text**

Comment: Hi Mike, was this problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the difference.

```
richard=> SELECT to_tsvector('simple', 'This day is a good day.  Šodiena ir laba ir diena');
                                    to_tsvector                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 'a':4 'day':2,6 'diena':11 'good':5 'ir':8,10 'is':3 'laba':9 'this':1 'šodiena':7
(1 row)

richard=> SELECT to_tsvector('simple', 'This day is a good day. Šodiena ir laba ir diena');
                                    to_tsvector                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 'a':4 'day':2,6 'diena':11 'good':5 'ir':8,10 'is':3 'laba':9 'this':1 'šodiena':7
(1 row)
```

I am running PG v13.2 on Debian with the "english" default text-search catalogue and UTF8 client+server encoding with "en_GB.UTF-8" locale.

The text-search settings shouldn't make a difference I don't think, since you've specified "simple" explicitly.

Maybe something isn't reaching the database as UTF8 somehow?

Comment: I have the same settings. English as text-search cat, UTF8 in both client and server enc. I have no other issues with UTF-8 data. I don't even know which way to look to fix this..